# webview android minimize Java script loading time

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I am doing hybird JQM application using phone gap. Now to load index.html in webview it takes much time as there are 15-20 java script refences in html.

please suggest approches for minimizing JS loading time or any parallel loading

Answer (score 1):

use [BackboneJs](http://backbonejs.org/) and [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) for asynchronous loading of javascript files

Answer (score 0):

Minify & merge your js files into 1-5 files.  Currently I use a [grunt + uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) via node in my applications for this.

If you're using tightly coupled code, you can do a single file, and use something stronger like google closure compiler for this... I find that uglify + merge is sufficient.

---

Alternatively, act like it's 2003 and pre-render your pages using server-side postbacks for mobile browsers.